# Disabling mnemonics in the menu bar while keeping button mnemonics in GTK2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, menu, gtk2

I would like to disable mnemonics in the menu bar because they interfere with keyboard shortcuts in some applications -- the terminal, for example -- but I would like to keep mnemonics for buttons in dialogs. After having read the [GTK2 Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-auto-mnemonics), I have set `gtk-enable-accels=0` but it doesn't work.

EDIT: I have also realized that `gtk-enable-accels=0` breaks some keyboard shortcuts in the terminal `Control-Shift-C` for copying, for example).